# Issues in batch script while using reg query

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

```
@echo off

Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters" /v SearchList >NUL 2>&1

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto VPN_Active
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto VPN_Not_Active

:VPN_Active
goto end

:VPN_Not_Active

:end
```

Above was my registry key need help if my registry key values are different

Example if registry key value was "1,2,3" or "1,2" my script need to goto vpn active or else it need to goto vpn_not_active.

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far? please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Comment: You need to research that registry key, its values, and possibly those of its subkeys. My understanding was that `SearchList` contains a string of up to six, _I think_, comma separated overriding domain suffixes which are searched in order left to right. For that reason, I do not believe that you're going about the task in the correct manner.